# Calculate the cumulative probability for a particular hand of poker

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm currently attempting to calculate the probability of someone having a hand just as good or better than any given three of a kind, two pair, one pair, or high hand.

This is in the context of 5 card draw poker.

I know the cumulative probabilities for these types of hands from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability):

High hand = 100%
One Pair = 49.9%
Two Pair = 7.62%
Three of a Kind = 2.87%

However, I'm looking to calculate the the cumulative probability for a particular hand e.g. 8D, 6D, 5S, 4C, 3C - how can I calculate the probability of drawing just as good a hand or better? (D, S, C, H being suits)

This is assuming 52 cards. This is assuming one other player, calculating the probability of drawing a better hand than your current one, with the 47 cards remaining.

Comment: is this assuming 2 players and 52 cards?  It's quite tricky, the odds for the opponent are skewed by the cards in your hand that make up the score of the hand, but also the other cards  - so for example if you have 2 kings, it might be harder for your opponent to have 2 kings, but then also, you have a maximum of 1 Ace in your hand, so he has at least 3 aces to aim at - there's stuff to work out

Comment: @Cato I've edited the question - I don't need to account for the possibility of other players having the certain cards, just the raw probability of drawing a better hand than the given one, given a deck of 52 cards

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'll do a Royal flush - you get a royal flush, what is the chances your opponent has one?

There are 4 Royal flushes, each are particular combinations of the 52C5 deal you can get, prob = 4 in 52C5 , is  1 in 649740

chances your opponent also has a royal flush from the 47 cards remaining (there are 3 royal flushes left - 3 particular hands from the cards left give him it)

3 in 47C5 = 1 , turns out as 1 in 511313

does you getting a royal flush really make it easier for your opponent to also have one??

---

i guess what you might be looking for is - if one hand is 2 kings, then how many hands are better than 2 kings - you should be able to get the numbers of high hands available, as compared to all hands, and we should be able to get how many of each 2 of a kind exist (e.g. 2 kings can  exist with any 2 kings from 4 (6 ways) multiplied by ways of getting  3 cards that do not form pairs

---

you want chance of beating king high for example?

Comment: In this case a royal flush doesn't work particularly well here, as I'm only working with high hands, one pair, two pairs, and three of a kind. In the case of a royal flush there's only one particular type of hand in that category of hand, whereas an opponent could also have a high hand that is better than yours. I'm looking to calculate, given a particular high hand for example, the probability of someone having just as good a hand or better.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for! Given king high or 2 kings, what is the chance that someone has the same hand or better?

Comment: I reckon the worst hand is 7 high, you need the other cards to be from  'a 2' and then three from 3,4,5,6 (but exclude flushes) - so there are 4 x ((4^4 - 1) x 4C3 = 408 - so it should be beaten 99.99% of the time (assuming you've got a 50% chance of getting a 7 high that is better

Comment: how many hands are worse than king high?  you need to get 5 different from 2-Q, excluding runs and flushes - so I make that 11C5 x (4^5 - 4) - 8 x (4^5 - 4)  = 463080 out of 2598960 - so with king high, there is less than 20% they will be queen high or worse - i've not worked out both king high, then used a tie break yet

Comment: I think the best way to do it is to make a database of all hands, then rank them (slightly tricky)

Comment: Ah okay, I understand the idea behind it. Thanks!